# How to change the color scheme for Material UI tabs?

Tags: material-ui

I'm looking to change the color scheme for Material UI Tab, with white background and green indicator and text.

Here's what i did as of now,

demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { orange, pink, green, lightGreen } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

function TabContainer(props) {
  return (
    <Typography component="div" style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTabs: {
      indicator: {
        backgroundColor: green[700]
      }
    },
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
          color: green[700]
        }
      },
      selected: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        color: green[700],
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: green[100],
          color: green[700]
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

class SimpleTabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>
          <AppBar position="static">
            <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <Tab label="Item One" />
              <Tab label="Item Two" />
              <Tab label="Item Three" href="#basic-tabs" />
            </Tabs>
          </AppBar>
          {value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
          {value === 1 && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
          {value === 2 && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

SimpleTabs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default SimpleTabs;
```

And the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Demo from './demo';

const rootElement = document.querySelector('#root');
if (rootElement) {
  render(<Demo />, rootElement);
}
```

As of now, the Tabs shows the intended color scheme but doesn't stay that way, only hovering over shows the White-Green color scheme. Also it has a blue background over Tabs, that i want to change to white as well.

I have taken reference form an earlier answer and did the changes. Here is the codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/mui3-how-to-override-tab-theme-forked-qexyf?file=/index.js:0-205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See improved [LIVE example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui3-how-to-override-tab-theme-forked-3nd4t?file=/demo.js:623-1196) and overriden config below with comments

[image]

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTabs: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" // overrides blue background for panel
      },
      indicator: {
        backgroundColor: green[700]
      }
    },
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        "&$selected": { // proper way for styling selected tab
          color: green[700],

          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: green[100],
            color: green[900]
          }
        }
      },
      wrapper: { // styles tab value
        color: green[500]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Errors in console (in your example) already had some useful tips. Follow them and make changes according [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs)
[image]

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )

Comment: You don't need to add background color to `MuiTab-root` in this example. The background color is already set on the `MuiTabs-root`.

Comment: Perfectly, working. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

MUI is showing the theme on hover because you specified:

```js
MuiTab: {
  root: {
    "&:hover": {
      // hover theme here ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note the `&:hover` specified under `MuiTab-root`.

To get the theme displaying for the selected item, try this:

```js
MuiTab: {
  root: {
    "&$selected": { // or "&.Mui-selected" in your example
      // selected theme here ...
    }
  }
}
```

See: [Use `$ruleName` to reference a local rule within the same style sheet](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet)

You should also take a look at the console for some helpful logs:

```sh
Material-UI: The `MuiTab` component increases the CSS specificity of the `selected` internal state.
You can not override it like this: 
{
  "root": {
    ... // shortened for brevity
  },
  ..., // shortened for brevity
  "selected": {
    ... // shortened for brevity
  }
}

Instead, you need to use the $ruleName syntax:
{
  "root": {
    "&$selected": {
      ... // shortened for brevity
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll be checking it, allow me some time.

Comment: Apologies for being late, This solution also working as expected. Thanks for the guidance.